# google chrome bug with pre-wrap

Tags: css, google-chrome

What I'm trying to achieve is to have **sequences whitespaces in a textarea preserved and words not broken at the end of the line**.

so according to this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

when we set

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

the WHITESPACES should be preserved and the words not splitted at the end.

However as this jsfiddle demonstrates, google chrome does not preserve sequences of whitespaces ( there are many spaces in the textarea but chrome displays less. Notice how every other browser displays them, but chrome no ).

http://jsfiddle.net/LXUEe/2/

Is there any solution to this problem ?

I can preserve the whitespaces by using:

```
white-space: pre;
```

but then all long words split at the end of the line ( though only for chrome... )

Is there any solution ?

Thanks in advance!

**edit**: try to continually enter spaces at a line at that jsfiddle. the cursor will get stucked once it reaches the far right end and won't go under in the next line ( chrome )

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you want

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome 26 as FireFox 18.

Comment: I believe what @MIrrorMirror asking was Webkit based browsers, including Chrome and Safari, renders textarea differently than non-webkit browsers. To see the difference, checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXUEe/6/) in Webkit and non-Webkit based browsers. Note that in non-webkit browsers, the last word `break` is not visible because the textarea is not large enough to fit all characters. In webkit browsers, however, the word is visible because some spaces (that causes line breaks) are collapsed. I have no clues whether this is a bug or a feature, but it indeed renders differently.

Comment: @JustinLau exactly, despite despite the fact that white spaces should NOT be collapsed in pre-wrap ( as per definition ), google chrome wraps them. I noticed the problem in a text-area text editor, when i tried to insert continuous spaces, once the cursor reaches the end of the line, it stucks there ( collapsing )

Comment: @Mooseman in chrome 24, there is no empty line ( full of spaces ) between the line containing "not" and the line containing "break". The problem is more obvious in JustinLau example ( with even more spaces )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PqCsD/2/ I don't see the problem here. I count the exact number of spaces that are there in the textarea.

Comment: @AdhipGupta go to any of those lines ( in chrome ) and try to enter more spaces ( by hand ) see what happens. enter them in the Result pane, not in the design html pane. you can't enter by hand any more spaces, they get collapsed

Comment: @MIrrorMirror Thanks, that does explain the problem better - but I still can work with it as per your use case in my example.

I clicked inside the textarea, hit return added a word - then added a few spaces, then another word, then loads of spaces (about 20) and then a few words. I could always count the exact number of spaces that were inserted (and had to press the back arrow those many times) to reach the previous character.

Comment: @AdhipGupta, just try what i said: just continue enter spaces until the cursor reaches the right-end of the textarea. it will stuck there ( spaces get collapsed )

Answer (score 8):

I'd say Chrome is the only browser correctly following [W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model).

Look at the second point 4

> If spaces (U+0020) or tabs (U+0009) at the end of a line have
>   **'white-space' set to 'pre-wrap', UAs may visually collapse them**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks that's interesting. If that's the case, how are we supposed to have a textarea which a) doesn't break words at the end of the line and b) doesn't collapse white-spaces, instead moves them to the next line ?

Comment: I should say however that this w3c recommendation contradicts the definition they give half a page above "pre-wrap
    This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.".

Comment: one solution would be using "white-space: pre;" but in google chrome that breaks words at the end of the line.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror I think the best cross-browsers approach would be to use javascript defined editor rather than `<textarea>` then.

Comment: @JustinLau I wouldn't like to go the contenteditable way. textareas are fine for my purpose, it's that chrome screws up pre-wrap by having a totally different behaviour than the others browsers.

Comment: I guess the W3C in general is trying to make rules based on reasonable - realistic use cases...(that's why the original margin collapsing exists anyway-even though strictly speaking it may seem like "an exception") Why are you trying to achieve what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So if I got it right, you want the text to overflow the textbox border, right?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos what i want to do, is have chrome have the SAME behaviour as firefox, opera, IE. That is, when the user continually enters spaces, the cursor doesn't "stuck" at the end of the line, it should go to the next line instead